# how can i have two exoplayer in one activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-videoview, exoplayer

in **android studio(kotlin)**, i want to have, ***two*** **exoplayers** in **one activity**.
and i know this depends on hardware's limitations.
*(some devices can only display one video at each activity , in the moment)*
but there is some way to handle this request.

for example, we have two **exoplayer1** and **exoplayer2**.
we have both of them in our activity but **at any moment**, **one of them can be active**.

for achieve this, when exoplayer1 wants to work, the exoplayer2 must be destroy.And vice versa .

i destroy exoplayer1 an exoplayer2 by this code

```
exoplayer1.removeAllViews()
exoplayer2.removeAllViews()
```

but, when i want to active again this exoplayers, i can't do it.

there is any way to **re-active exoplayer** after **removeallViews**?

Comment: ExoPlayer supports multiple instances, why do you need to destroy them, rather than just stopping the other one.  That might even be automatic if you use mediasession.